# how to customize toc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

how to remove number counter in toc?

this my current output:
[image]

i want this out put:

[image]

```
1. BAB I PENDAHULUAN
   1.1 Latar Bekalang
   1.2 Maksud dan Tujuan Magang
   1.3 Waktu dan Ruang Lingkup Pelaksanaan Kerja Magang
2. BAB II GAMBARAN UMUM PERUSAHAAN
   2.1 Sejarah Perushaan
```

to this one below

```
BAB I PENDAHULUAN
   1.1 Latar Bekalang
   1.2 Maksud dan Tujuan Magang
   1.3 Waktu dan Ruang Lingkup Pelaksanaan Kerja Magang
BAB II GAMBARAN UMUM PERUSAHAAN
   2.1 Sejarah Perushaan
```

---

### laporan.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\renewcommand{\contentsname }{DAFTAR ISI}


\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={it},name={Gambar},labelsep=period}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\chaptertitleformat}{%
  \thechapter.\ \chaptername\space \Roman{chapter}%
}

% \usepackage{sectsty}
% \allsectionsfont{\centering}

\title{Laporan Magang}
\author{Gopher}
% \date{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalsize\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{indentfirst}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{Daftar Isi}
\clearpage



\input{bab1.tex}
\clearpage

\input{bab2.tex}
\clearpage
\input{bab3.tex}

\end{document}
```

---

### bab1.tex

```
\section[BAB I PENDAHULUAN]{BAB I\\ PENDAHULUAN}

\subsection{Latar Belakang}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add a minimal example of your document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal example code?

Comment: This could be done, I suspect, with  `titletoc`, which comes with `titlesec`, but I wonder, if some words in your language, like ‘Bab’,  have a generic meaning (Part??), so their appear.ance in the toc could be automated via `babel`.

Comment: BAB its like Chapter just in bahasa, i just want remove auto counting number infront of section in toc : (from) `1 BAB I blah..blah` (to) `BAB I blah..blah`

Comment: Beware there's no chapter in the article class. If you want to have chapters, use the report or book class.